# Swift 3 type casting error

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have this code working fine in swift 2.2

```
let arrayNib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("VehicleDetailsTableViewCell", owner: nil, options: nil) as! NSArray
```

While in swift 3.0 code gives me error

> Cannot convert value of [Any]? to type NSArray in coercion

Comment: Friendly note: this is Swift. You should use a Swift array instead of NSArray.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
let arrayNib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("VehicleDetailsTableViewCell", owner: nil, options: nil)! as [Any]
print (arrayNib)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can use it like

```
let arrayNib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("VehicleDetailsTableViewCell", owner: nil, options: nil)
```

It gives me array of [Any?].

Answer (score 0):

Error is pretty explicit.

You're trying convert `Optional<T>` to say `U`.

While `T` is castable to `U`, `Optional<T>` **is not**.

If you want you may cast `Optional<T>` to `Optional<U>`.
Like in your case `[Any]?` to `NSArray?`.

But I strongly recommend to use `Swift` array and add some real types.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, there is a new array type in Swift that is being used in new APIs; here's what a playground says:

[image]

I guess a follow-up question is whether using NSArray is essential.